# How to break cols in bootstrap3

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

i have 4 box in code below, default in medium size, all 4 box are in one row. It is OK.
In x-small size (mobile) all 4 box will fullwith is OK.

But in small size (>768px & <1000px): how i can make Box1,Box2 in row1, and Box3, Box4 in row 2

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
$('head').append('<meta name="viewport" content="width=1000px, initial-scale=1"/>');
});
```

```css
.box {
border:solid 1px red;
}
.box3,.box4 {
background:grey;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="box col-sm-6 col-md-4" id="col4_1">Box 1</div>
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-8">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="box col-sm-12 col-md-4" id="col4_2">Box 2</div>
        <div class="box box3 col-sm-12 col-md-4" id="col4_3">Box 3</div>
        <div class="box box4 col-sm-12 col-md-4" id="col4_4">Box 4</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you look at the docs and add col-12, col-sm-12, col-md-12, col-lg12, col-xl-12. If you want for a certain size to have 2 rows (Each with 2 columns), you should use, say col-md-6 for each. A row has 12 columns, so using 6 will render 2 boxes per row. Using 12 will put one box per row. See docs https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/layout/grid/

Comment: @aepure the question is about bootstrap 3

Comment: I think without `HTML` changes, you can't.

Comment: Thanks, I updated my answer to use boostrap 3. The principle is the same. But with HTML changes. http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid

Comment: As far as I understand he want to keep first cell width 1/3 on -md- ,while another cells are getting 2/3 of screen

Comment: @Banzay: you right

Comment: @MuhammadUsman: yes, i can changes html, but do you can suggest me correct layout

Answer (score 0):

Since you have a specific width to check, you need to use [Media Queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries). Not sure if this will work, but you can start from this

```
@media all and (max-width: 1000px) {
    #col4_1,
    #col4_2,
    #col4_3,
    #col4_4
    {
        width: 50%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try two parts: one visible to "xtra-small" and the other visible to "small" screens

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row" hidden-sm>
    <div class="box col-sm-6 col-md-4" id="col4_1">Box 1</div>
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-8">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="box col-sm-12 col-md-4" id="col4_2">Box 2</div>
        <div class="box box3 col-sm-12 col-md-4" id="col4_3">Box 3</div>
        <div class="box box4 col-sm-12 col-md-4" id="col4_4">Box 4</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="row" hidden-xs>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="box col-sm-6" id="col4_1">Box 1</div>
        <div class="box col-sm-6">Box 2</div>
    </div
    <div class="row">
        <div class="box box3 col-sm-6" id="col4_3">Box 3</div>
        <div class="box box4 col-sm-6" id="col4_4">Box 4</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you look at the [docs](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid).

A row has 12 columns. If you make a box occupy:

- 12 columns, each box will occupy one row.
- 6 columns, you will have 2 boxes per row.
- 4 columns, you'll get 3 boxes per row.
- 3 columns, you'll get all 4 boxes on a row.

For example, for medium screen, you can make each box **col-md-6** and you will get 2 boxes per row on a medium screen.

From the [docs](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid):

- .col-xs- is for extra small
- .col-sm- is for small
- .col-md- is for medium

And please put **all your boxes in the same row**

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
$('head').append('<meta name="viewport" content="width=1000px, initial-scale=1"/>');
});
```

```css
.box {
border:solid 1px red;
}
.box3,.box4 {
background:grey;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="box col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3" id="col4_1">Box 1</div>
    <div class="box col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3" id="col4_2">Box 2</div>
    <div class="box col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3 box3 " id="col4_3">Box 3</div>
    <div class="box col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3 box4" id="col4_4">Box 4</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: all boxes in the same row not correct layout ratio of my site. I want Box1 1/3 (col-md-4) of screen, while all another box are getting 2/3 of screen